# Flutter NetworkImage vs cached_network_image

Tags: flutter

Flutter recommends using `cached_network_image` here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images. I used it and it worked fine. I tried `NetworkImage` and it worked, too.

I read from the doc that `NetworkImage` also caches the downloaded image locally. So what's the point in using `cached_network_image` instead of `NetworkImage`? Is there a comparison of how their caching strategies differentiate from one another?

Comment: the question has been answered properly please mark the answer correct so that it can guide other developers properly

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The difference is significant and really helpful too...as you know fetching image from network takes time so [cached network image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) provides you options for space holder to show when loading and error widget when can't load which are not there in [NetworkImage](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image). As a developer, you must be ready for every situation so that's the reason for recommending [cached network images.](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

UPDATE:
[ImageNetwork](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image) now has a loadingBuilder and errorbuilder parameters, so it too can now show a loading indicator similar to [cached network image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image). But in CachedImageNetwork once the image is loaded it's cached in the system until the URL changes, which gives faster loading of the image every time and there are also many more features to explore please see [official read me documents](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image).

So still I prefer [cachedNetworkImage](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) until [NetworkImage](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image) has similar features.

Hope you understand! Otherwise, let me know in the comments down below!

Comment: Thanks! The placeholder is indeed helpful. Besides this, what about the caching strategy wise?

Comment: For example where do they save temporary files, are they both save and get cached image using URL, after how long should the same url be reloaded, etc.

Comment: The cached network images stores and retrieves files using the flutter_cache_manager. A CacheManager to download and cache files in the cache directory of the app. Various settings on how long to keep a file can be changed.It uses the cache-control http header to efficiently retrieve files. Hope you have understood...for detailed information can be found in the docs of these 2 plugins. If you feel I could help you then please mark as accepted and upvote!

Comment: Thanks, now I know where to look at and study. Just want to confirm: I should look into `cache_manager.dart` for `cached_network_image` and `image_cache.dart` for `NetworkImage`, right?

Comment: Any thing about which you want to know by seeing source code which you have used in your code then press ctrl and then click on that you will be automatically redirected to the respective file as well as respective class or method or anything. But I suggest read the docs given in the pubdev site of thses plugins but reading code is also a really good way to understand.

Comment: Image.network now has a loadingBuilder parameter, so it too can now show a loading indicator. Does this mean that there is now no advantage of using CachedNetworkImage over Image.network?

Comment: The name of both shows the difference, i.e one is only ImageNetwork and other cachedImageNetwork, so the word cached makes all difference, in cachedImageNetwork once the image is loaded its cached in the system until the URL changes, which gives faster loading of the image every time and there are also many more features to explore please see official read me documents.

Comment: I have edited my answer and now it's up to date, please check it out. Hope it helps, if yes upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I used both and dont see any significant load time improvement, everyone my app launches, it appears images are being downloaded.

Just for info, I am keeping the images on Azure blob storage.
Image URLs are part of the mongodb.

These images have been captured from camera or selected from the gallery and then uploaded to azure.
What could be the reason the caching seems  not to be working.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is the cashed network image have a loading indicator when the image being fetched from the internet and show error icon if happen something error while fetching the image. While network image don't have this features.  https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image